# Laravel Register error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to register through my register form in laravel and I'm getting an error :
 **MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message**

[RegisterController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r9dx.png)

[Register.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH7dC.png)

[users table in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE8jJ.png)

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsHox.png)

Comment: what about the route ?

Comment: Make an effort and paste your code as __text__.

Answer (score 1):

change the form action to `register`

```
<form action="/register">
```